# How to use sscanf to make sure an input is of string length 1 only using stdio.h

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, scanf

Basically I have to use if statements:

```
char post[2];
if ((1 == sscanf(origstr, "%1d%1s", num,post)) && (*num>0) && (*num<8))
```

The problem with this is when I type in ' 5' or '5 ', the if statement is still true when I want it to be false. Btw: I have post here so a user can't enter 4.5. Because when they do, 4 goes into num and '.' goes into post[0] which would make sscanf==2.

For clarity:
I want '   5', '5   ', ' 5 ' etc to fail the if statement
I only want '1','2',...,'7' to pass

Comment: I think that you can check the scanf output by using the ASCII table. Letters are between 65 & 122.

Comment: `char post[2]; if sscanf(origstr, "%1[1234567]%*c", post) == 1) Good(); /* num = post[0] - '0'; */`

Comment: @chux is $1 a typo? It's giving me an error...

Comment: There is no `$` in my comment.  Suggest double checking your transcription.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"%[]"` to restrict acceptable `char`.  Use `"%1[]"` to limit the length to 1 `char` only.  `"%*c"` will scan any 1 `char` except `'\0'` as `sscanf()` will not offer this `char`.  The `sscanf()` return value will be 0, 1 or 2.  2 implies too many, 0 implies no `'1'` to `'7'`.

```
char numbuf[2];
char post;
if (sscanf(origstr, "%1[1234567]%c", numbuf, &post) == 1) {
  // Good
  num = numbuf[0] - '0';
}
```

Or alternatively

```
char num;
char post;
if ((sscanf(origstr, "%c%c", &num, &post) == 1) && (num >= '1')  && 
     (num <= '7')) {
  // Good
  num = num - '0';
}
```

Or alternatively

```
int num;
int n;
if ((sscanf(origstr, "%d%n", &num, &n) == 1) && (num >= 1)  &&  (num <= 7) && 
    (n == 1)) {
  // Good
}
```

Or alternatively

```
int num;
int n;
if ((sscanf(origstr, "%o%n", &num, &n) == 1) && (num >= 1) && (n == 1)) {
  // Good
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It had better the following manner than stick to sscanf is lighter treatment to the easy-to-understand and easy.

```
if(*origstr && '0' < *origstr && *origstr < '8' && !origstr[1])//origstr[1] == '\n' ?
    sscanf(origstr, "%d", num);//*num = origstr - '0';
```